# converting a character element to an object in R

Tags: r, string, function

I was wondering if it might be possible to convert an charterer element e.g., `"high"` to an object with the same name i.e., `high`?

Here is what I mean in R code (*my desired outcome*):

*(Note: Think of below as a function `what` can be anything, `d` can be anything)*

```
what <- "high"
   d <- 1:4
high <- d # Here use `what` and turn "high" to high and assign object `d` to high
```

Comment: It’s possible but almost always a mistake. What is your use-case for doing this? There are probably better ways.

Comment: Do you mean this? `what <- "high" ; d <- 1:4 ; assign(what, d) ; high`

Comment: @Reza I don’t understand: your code works as-is *without* changing the variable name `dum`. At any rate I recommend against the hacky solution that Darren proposed. Apart from not being helpful in your case, it has a few undesirable properties (it destroys referential transparency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don’t want to do this, because it breaks [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) and adds unnecessary complexity: in particular, it makes it unpredictable which variables exist during the execution of your code, which makes code harder to read, maintain and debug.

At any rate, in your case assigning to a variable with a non-fixed name doesn’t actually help with constructing your model matrix. Luckily it is also unnecessary in your case. Your existing code works as-is. But if you want to change the output column names, do so on the *column name level*, not on the *variable name level*:

```
foo <- function(data, what) {
    dum <- data[[what]]
    if (! is.character(dum)) stop('Not a character variable.', call. = FALSE)
    model <- data.frame(model.matrix(~ dum))[-1L]
    colnames(model) <- sub('^dum', what, colnames(model))
    model
}
```

Alternatively, and in this case even easier, construct the formula from `what`:

```
foo <- function(data, what) {
    if (! is.character(data[[what]])) stop('Not a character variable.', call. = FALSE)
    formula = as.formula(paste('~', what))
    data.frame(model.matrix(formula, data = data))[-1L]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**assign** function might be the solution you are looking for.

```
what <- "high"
   d <- 1:4
high <- d

assign(what,d)

assign("high",d)
```

By this way, the character and objects can be played with

Other things, which I tried are using

```
as.name
```

function, which will kind of remove the quotes. But it will lead to error in assignment.

Comment: `as.name` isn’t really useful here, so why mention it?

Comment: It is kind of the first logic that a newbie will try. Just to make clear that "Don't try it"